# If $\kappa$ is a contractive operator on $C_0(ℝ)$, is $λ(κ-\text{id})$ the generator of a Feller semigroup?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, markov-process, stochastic-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

Let $E$ be a locally compact separable metric space, $$C_0(E):=\left\{f\in C(E):\left\{|f|\ge\varepsilon\right\}\text{ is compact for all }\varepsilon>0\right\},$$ $\kappa$ be a Markov kernel on $(E,\mathcal B(E))$, $$\kappa f:=\int\kappa(\;\cdot\;,{\rm d}y)f(y)\;\;\;\text{for bounded Borel measurable}f:E\to\mathbb R,$$ $\lambda\ge0$ and $$Af:=\lambda(\kappa f-f)\;\;\;\text{for }f\in C_0(E).$$

> Are we able to show that $A$ is the generator of a Feller semigroup (as defined in [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3150679/47771)) on $C_0(E)$?

Note that $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ is the generator of the uniformly continuous semigroup $$S(t)f:=e^{tA}f\;\;\;\text{for }f\in C_0(E)\text{ and }t\ge0.$$

**EDIT**: For whatever it may be useful, we may note that since $\kappa$ is contractive, $$\lambda\left\|\kappa f\right\|_\infty\le\lambda\left\|f\right\|_\infty\le(\lambda+\mu)\left\|f\right\|_\infty\tag2$$ and hence $$\left\|A_\mu f\right\|_\infty\ge\left|(\lambda+\mu)\left\|f\right\|_\infty-\lambda\left\|\kappa f\right\|_\infty\right|\ge(\lambda+\mu)\left\|f\right\|_\infty-\lambda\left\|f\right\|_\infty=\mu\left\|f\right\|_\infty\tag3$$ by the reverse triangle inequality for all bounded Borel measurable $f:E\to\mathbb R$ (in particular, for $f\in C_0(E)$) and $\mu\ge0$. So, $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ is dissipative.

**EDIT**2: It's trivial to see that $A$ satisfies the nonnegative maximum principle: If $f\in C_0(E)$ and $x_0\in E$ with $$f(x_0)=\sup_{x\in E}f(x)$$ (it's not necessary to assume $f(x_0)\ge0$ for the following conclusion), then $$(\kappa f)(x_0)-f(x_0)=\int\kappa(x_0,{\rm d}y)\underbrace{\left(f(y)-f(x_0)\right)}_{\le\:0}\le0\tag4.$$

Comment: Basically it seems like you are asking about the semigroup $S'(t) = e^{-\lambda t} S(\lambda t)$. This is going to be strongly continuous since the original semigroup $S(t)$ is, and because $|e^{-\lambda t}-1| \leq \lambda t$.

Comment: @Shalop Thank you for your comment. I guess this shows indeed strong continuity. However, it's still not clear to me why $S(t)C_0(E)\subseteq C_0(E)$. (I thought it might be easier to show that $(S(t))_{t\ge0}$ is Feller by showing the mentioned properties of the generator, but if you know how we directly show that this semigroup is Felelr, this would be fine as well for me.)

Comment: Of course if $\kappa$ maps $C_0$ to $C_0$, then clearly $e^{t\kappa}$ maps $C_0$ to $C_0$. Because you assumed “\kappa is a contractive operator on $C_0$”.

Comment: @Shalop Sorry, I guess the title is misleading. I only assume that $\kappa$ is a Markov kernel on $(E,\mathcal B(E))$ and hence induces a contractive operator on the Banach space of bounded Borel measurable $f:E\to\mathbb R$ (by the given definition of $\kappa f$) equipped with the sup-norm. So, in particular, $\left\|\kappa f\right\|_\infty\le\left\|f\right\|_\infty$ for all $f\in C_0(E)$, but we don't know that $\kappa f\in C_0(E)$.

Comment: Then the answer is no. Basically set $E=[0,1]$. Then define $\kappa$ by $(\kappa f)(x) = f(0)$ for $x \in [0,1/2]$ and define $(\kappa f)(x) = f(1)$ for $x \in (1/2,1]$. It is clear that $\kappa$ acts contractively on bounded measurable functions. However, $\kappa$ clearly fails to send $C(E)$ to itself. Since $\kappa$ is idempotent, it then follows that $e^{t\kappa} = I + (e^t-1)\kappa$ also fails to send $C(E)$ to itself.

Comment: @Shalop What am I missing then? Kallenberg seems to assume that a [pseudo-Poisson process](http://tinyurl.com/y2y4kj5u) is [Feller](http://tinyurl.com/yxu6at24) in the [proof of Theorem 17.28](https://books.google.de/books?id=uL7UBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA333&lpg=PA333&dq=%22extends+the+approximations+for+random+walks+obtained%22+kallenberg&source=bl&ots=iip2ffD-3j&sig=ACfU3U20CA66Jbn-6yssGRqo4fiZkGc8YQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwimjuqTisrhAhXEZFAKHWkICX4Q6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22extends%20the%20approximations%20for%20random%20walks%20obtained%22%20kallenberg&f=false).

Comment: Well it’s clear that you need kappa to map C_0 into itself, so the topology on E needs to be fine enough for that to hold. Hence you should go back and look at whatever Kallenberg assumes in his definitions.

Comment: @Shalop He assumes that $E$ is a locally compact separable metric space. Does that change anything? It would actually enough for me if $S(t)$ and $A$ map $C_b(E)$ onto $C_b(E)$. But this doesn't seem to hold for general $\kappa$, if I'm not missing something.